# _openai_scripts.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, openai-api

Working on a python script using the OpenAI API. When I try to run the script this is my Mac terminal output:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: can't open file '/Users/me/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/openai/_openai_scripts.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I can confirm there is no such file in that folder, but not sure what to do about it.

**Edits in Response to Comments:**

Here is the part of my script that references OpenAI:

```
# Step 2: Send HTML to ChatGPT API
api_key = "..."
prompt = f"HTML source code:\n\n{html_content}\n\nExtract the following information:\n1. Church Name\n2. Pastor Name\n3. Pastor Email"
response = openai.Completion.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",  # Use the appropriate model
    messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
        {"role": "user", "content": prompt},
    ],
    api_key=api_key
)

chat_output = response.choices[0].message["content"].strip()
```

And the command I'm using to run the script is:

```
python3 chatgpt-analyze.py
```

Here is the result of running the `pip3 show openai` command:

```
Name: openai
Version: 1.12.0
Summary: The official Python library for the openai API
Home-page:
Author:
Author-email: OpenAI <support@openai.com>
License:
Location: /Users/me/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages Requires: anyio, distro, httpx, pydantic, sniffio, tqdm, typing-extensions
Required-by:
```

But if I try to run e.g., `openai --help` I get the same error:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: can't open file '/Users/me/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/openai/_openai_scripts.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: _can confirm there is no such file in that folder_ If that file doesn't exist, then why are you trying to run it?  I don't understand.

Comment: Could you share command that you are running this script with? As @JohnGordon said it's difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Are you new in python world?

Comment: @JohnGordon I didn't know I was trying to run it... ha! Thanks for your comment/question.

Comment: @ravenwing done thanks! Would still appreciate help with this as I am stuck.

Comment: @Drewdavid Where are you stuck?

Comment: @RokBenko I don't know how to fix this error. Why is the file missing and what should be in it? Do I need to create it manually? Can it be empty? I installed the openai package using pip3 but it seems that wasn't enough. Thanks =)

Comment: This is really strange... I search for _openai_scripts.py file and didn't find any mentions...

For sure you should not create files manualy in `site-packages`.
Another - last request - could you also add line how you import openai module in your script?

Comment: @ravenwing : `import openai` - understood thanks!